# Relative links not working after migrating Wordpress site from live to local using XAMPP

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp, localhost

While setting up a local Wordpress site, if I have a relative link like this:

```
<img src="/wp-content/themes/Tree/assets/images/logo.svg" alt="logo.svg" width="95" height="29">
```

When I click on it, it will go to:

```
http://localhost/wp-content/themes/Tree/assets/images/logo.svg
```

instead of

```
http://localhost/mysite_local/wp-content/themes/Tree/assets/images/logo.svg
```

`.htaccess` looks like this

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite_local/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /mysite_local/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I'm using XAMPP on Windows 10 to setup a local Wordpress development. All other steps have been performed successfully, and this is the last thing that's left not working.

- I tried going to Permalinks, and saving, but it did not help.
- I tried changing `DocumentRoot` in `httpd.conf` to:

  `DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/mysite_local"`
  `<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/mysite_local">`

But I get Error 500, apache `error.log` says this:

`AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

- I tried adding this to `wp-config.php`, but it didn't help

  `define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');`

  `define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');`
- Cleared cache/cookies/etc and restarted server multiple times while trying this ofc

How should I fix this?

Comment: If you change your document root, then the rewrite should probably not be to `/mysite_local/index.php` any more, but just `/index.php`

Comment: @CBroe Changed it, but now I get a site without any styling, and files are reported as 404 not found...

Comment: WordPress also uses _absolute_ URLs in a lot of places, so it might be that something doesn't match any more in that regard now. Figure out first of all, which case it actually is, regarding the stylesheets, and whatever "files" you are talking about.

Comment: @CBroe Disregarding changing root directory, how should this be done in general? With my current `.htaccess`, how can I tell the server to properly follow relative links on the local site?

Comment: Personally, I would set up a virtual host and local domain specifically for this, so that you can access the project via something like `http://mywpproject.local/`, without having an additional folder in the URL path. And plugins like WP Migrate can help with fixing any absolute URLs that might be part of database content.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you! I managed to set it up that way, I was totally heading in a wrong direction. I'll post a writeup soon.